# String manipulation, replacing " " with (space)

Tags: javascript, html, string, html-manipulation

I've been working on a function that changes the spaces between words into the string `" "`(space).

For example, `"Hello World. Hi there."` would become `"Hello(space)world.(space)Hi(space)there."`

EDIT: I'm trying to build this to a specific set of structured English which is as follows:

- set the initial value of result to an empty string
- for each index in the argument string
- if the character at that index is a space then
- append '(space)' to result
- else
- append the character at that index to result
- end if
- end for
- return result

Here is what I was able to come up with so far.:

```
function showSpaces(aString)
{
var word, letter;

word = aString
for var (count = 0; count < word.length; count = count + 1)

{
    letter = word.charAt(count);
    if (letter == " ")
    {
        return("(space)");
    }
    else
    {
        return(letter);
    }
}
}
```

Whenever I test this function call, nothing happens:

```
<INPUT TYPE = "button" NAME = "showSpacesButton"  VALUE ="Show spaces in a string as (space)"
        ONCLICK = "window.alert(showSpaces('Space: the final frontier'));">
```

I'm just beginning with JavaScript at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

-Ross.

Comment: There's no need to include the focal topic in the title. StackOverflow will prefix the page's title with the most popular tag (in this case, JavaScript).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
function showSpaces(aString)
{
    return aString.replace(/ /g,'(space)');
}
```

EDIT: to get your code working:

```
function showSpaces (aString)
{

    var word, letter,
        output = ""; // Add an output string

    word = aString;
    for (var count = 0; count < word.length; count = count + 1) // removed var after for

    {
        letter = word.charAt(count);
        if (letter == " ")
        {
            output += ("(space)"); // don't return, but build the string
        }
        else
        {
            output += (letter); // don't return, but build the string
        }
    }
    return output; // once the string has been build, return it

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great solution. My only problem is that I am trying to build it according to a specific set of structured English.

set the initial value of result to an empty string 
for each index in the argument string 
if the character at that index is a space then 
append '(space)' to result 
else 
append the character at that index to result   
 end if 
end for 
return result

Comment: @Ross, I've updated with comments in your algorithm. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Those comments are really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

No, "nothing" doesn't happen. It very rarely does. What happens is that you are getting a syntax error in the code because you used `for var (` instead of `for (var`.

If you fix that, you will notice that you only get the first character in the string, as you use `return` inside the loop instead of putting together a string and returning it after the loop.

You can do like this:

```
function showSpaces(word) {
  var letter, result = "";
  for (var count = 0; count < word.length; count++) {
    letter = word.charAt(count);
    if (letter == " ") {
      result += "(space)";
    } else {
      result += letter;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/pFkhs/

(Note: Using `+=` to concatenate strings performs badly for long strings.)

You can also use a regular expression to replace a string:

```
function showSpaces(word) {
  return word.replace(/ /g, "(space)");
}
```

Comment: a sound point you make about "Nothing not happening." I should look at things more closely. Many thanks for your tutorship explaining my "return." inside the loop, too. It's invaluable.